# TypeError: no implicit conversion of Fixnum into Hash - Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

### Did I try google?

Yes, I tried stack overflow, google, rubydocs, bunch of websites but there are *minimal* results to this and it's only ever mentioned indirectly. So yes, I did a lot of searching.

### What's working?

I run the following query:

```
requests = Request.where("customer_id = ? 
 AND request_method != ? 
  AND request_time 
   BETWEEN ? AND ?",
    customer.id, "OPTIONS", start_time, end_time).group('request_time')
```

As a result I get a bunch of values from the Database which look like this and this is **CORRECT**:

```
 #<ActiveRecord::Relation[#<Request id: 171792, request_time: "2022-04-04 14:07:20">,
   #<Request id: 171787, request_time: "2022-04-04 14:06:02">...]
```

***NOTE***: I didn't paste all the values because they have a similar structure.

### What's the problem?

After running the query I want to pass it to the variable `dates_init_hash = {}` and merge it whilst counting into `data[:requests]`:

```
dates_init_hash = {}
(start_time.to_date..end_time.to_date).each do |date|
  dates_init_hash[date] = 0
end

data[:requests] = dates_init_hash.merge(requests.count)
```

*Unfortunately*, I always seem to be getting the error:

```
ERROR -- : TypeError: no implicit conversion of Fixnum into Hash
```

### Expected

I should be getting a Hash like the following:

```
{ "2022-03-24"=>2, "2022-03-25"=>1, "2022-03-28"=>3, "2022-03-29"=>11}
```

### What I tried

1. I tried to convert the results to a hash before passing it over but this gave me the error that the `.to_h` method doesn't exist
2. `data[:requests] = dates_init_hash.merge({requests: requests.count })` works half-way still causing errors

### Questions

1. Why am I getting a Fixnum and why won't this work? How can I improve this? What would be the right way to solving this? I appreciate any kind of help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Why is the error happening?**

You are getting the error because when you run:

```rb
data[:requests] = dates_init_hash.merge(requests.count)
```

`dates_init_hash` is a hash, and `requests.count` is a number. So you are trying to merge a number into a hash, what is not allowed.

**How can I fix it?**

If what you want is to have the `dates_init_hash` with a mapping `date => number of requests that date`, you can do the following:

```rb
# initializes dates_init_hash with desired dates
dates_init_hash = {}
(start_time.to_date..end_time.to_date).each do |date|
  dates_init_hash[date.iso8601] = 0
end

# iterates over reuests and add 1 to the date in dates_init_hash for each request in the desired date
requests.each do |request|
  date = Date.parse(request[:request_time]).iso8601
  next if dates_init_hash[date].nil? 

  dates_init_hash[date] += 1
end
```

Then, `dates_init_hash` will be something like

```rb
{"2022-04-04"=>1, "2022-04-05"=>0, "2022-04-06"=>1, "2022-04-07"=>0}
```

Comment: Thanks! After implementing roughly this method it seems to be reacting as its supposed to!

Comment: I am now getting the error `undefined method gsub!' for 2022-04-05 14:30:29 UTC:Time` caused by the line:  `date = Date.parse(request[:request_time]).iso8601`

Comment: It seems like the `request_time` you're getting is not set a String, but as a Time object instead. Then, the `Date.parse` would not work. Does it work if you replace this line by `date = request.request_time.to_date.iso8601`? The idea here is to convert the Time object into a Date one, and then use this date (in iso8601).

Comment: Thanks that fixed it! How can i pass this over to the `data[:requests]`´ where i was usually merging it (which originally caused the error? I need the hashed values in the mentioned variable. Many thanks!

Comment: Nice! At this point, the variable `dates_init_hash` has the value like `{"2022-04-04"=>1, "2022-04-05"=>0, "2022-04-06"=>1, "2022-04-07"=>0}` (which is what you would expect, right?). I don't know how `data` is set, but assuming that it is a hash with the key `:requests`, and you want to set some value to this key having the hash with the `date => requests count`, you can simply assign `data[:requests] = dates_init_hash`. Is that what you would like to have for the `data` variable?

Comment: yes, perfect! Exactly what i needed bigtime lifesaver Marcos!, but im having a tiny issue and that's on me because i never mentioned it in my question, i have a  `data[:requests] = dates_init_hash` but i also have a `data[:error_requests]` which has the exact same structure (error caused due to `dates_init_hash.merge(error_requests.count)`). I want to do the same thing but if i pass over the same `dates_init_hash` it will pass over all the normal requests and not the ones counted for failed requests. Any tips here?.

Comment: no worries i fixed it by adding a second variable for the error_Requests! Fantastic stuff thanks man!